On the parity of number of integer solutions to $2x^2+yz=p$
Let $p$ be an odd prime number. We define the following set
$$S=\{(x,y,z)\in(1+2\mathbb{N})^3\mid 2x^2+yz=p\text{ and }y<z\}$$
What can we say about the parity of the cardinal $\sharp S$? I am particularly interested in the case $p\equiv7(\mathrm{mod}\,16)$. I have tested the first few such primes $p$, and it seems $\sharp S$ is an odd number. Is this true in general for $p\equiv7(\mathrm{mod}\,16)$? Any help would be appreciated!
I came to this question when I read Zagier's one-sentence proof of Fermat's sum of two squares theorem (see here): let $p$ be a prime such that $p\equiv1(\mathrm{mod}\,4)$ and set $S'=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{N}^3\mid x^2+4yz=p\}$. Then by constructing a certain involution on this $S'$ and showing that this involution has a unique fixed point, it is deduced that $\sharp S'$ is odd.
I have tried to construct a similar involution on $S$, yet it seems very difficult to realise this.

How are you defining $\mathbb{N}$?

$\mathbb{N}$ is the set of non-negative integers.

So $yz$ could be any odd number greater than 1?

Yes, you are right.

This is an extended comment. I believe
$$
S(p)=\sideset{}{'}\sum_{x=1}^{\sqrt{(p-3)/2}}\left\lfloor\frac{d(p-2x^2)}{2}\right\rfloor
$$
where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ and $\sideset{}{'}\sum$ sums over odds.
In PARI/GP, this is
S(p)=my(s); forstep(x=1,sqrtint((p-3)\2),2, s+=numdiv(p-2*x^2)\2); s

and I have tested that $S(p)$ is odd for $7\le p\le 10^8, p\equiv7\pmod{16}$:
forprimestep(p=7,1e8,16, if(S(p)%2==0, return(p)))

The calculation took about 40 minutes on a single core. This is definitely far enough that the behavior is suspicious; your conjecture seems reasonable. It does remind me of Zagier's construction.
Note that $2x^2\equiv2\pmod{16}$ when $x\equiv1\pmod2$ and so $p-2x^2\equiv5\pmod{16}$ when additionally $p\equiv7\pmod{16}.$ Since 5 is not a square mod 16,
$$
S(p)=\sideset{}{'}\sum_{x=1}^{\sqrt{(p-3)/2}} \frac{d(p-2x^2)}{2}
$$
when $p\equiv7\pmod{16}$ for what little that's worth.

Yes, I believe your expression for $S(p)$ is correct. Yet can you prove, using this expression, that $S(p)$ is odd?

@Mathew Nope! I have some bits and pieces that may be useful, plus a little calculation that demonstrates the reasonableness of your conjecture.

Some examples:
$\{2197, 3375, 4913\}, p=26234993,p\equiv 1(\mathrm{mod}\,16)$
$\{343, 1331, 6859\}, p=9364627,p\equiv 3(\mathrm{mod}\,16)$
$\{343, 729, 6859\}, p=5235509,p\equiv 5(\mathrm{mod}\,16)$
$\{343, 3375, 6859\}, p=23384423,p\equiv 7(\mathrm{mod}\,16)$
